# Why does the Linux kernel not use rust?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, performance, c, rust

I have heard that the Linux Kernel uses rust. I don't know much about the programming language except that it has the potential to run faster than C.

According to websites Rust is more safe than C because it's compilation process detects errors and imposes some restrictions. However if the compiled code does not follow those guidelines. You can compile Rust in unsafe mode which is more or less C except not C.

However when I looked up if Linux uses Rust the websites that told that C uses Rust. They are lying because I checked the Linux Kernel on GitHub and there is a place in the repository or project that says what percentage of code is being used in the repository or project and it says nothing for Rust.

According to the information I got about Rust and C, Rust seems to be much better because it is safer and runs faster than C in some situations. If that is so then why does Rust not use the Linux Kernel?

**Please correct me if I am wrong about my claims of Rust and C. I have never coded before but I like comparing languages to see which one is the best. Also if the only reason why the Linux Kernel does not use Rust is because all the Linux developers would have to learn a new language or get fired just say that.**

Comment: Just as a remark, the Linux kernel is significantly older than Rust. This is not an answer, but it's perhaps the first step toward one.

Comment: As the question itself is border-line "opinion-based" (could be interpreted as soliciting opinions about the relative benefit of Rust over C or the other way around; *this is an off-topic discussion on this site*), answers will need to be focused on the factual explanation of the decisions made by the Linux Kernel developers.

Comment: honestly, this question is answered by "because it doesn't". Rust didn't exist when it was created, it was created intentionally to build a UNIX-alike system (which includes writing it in state-of-the-art C), and there's a bazillion other languages that it's *not* written in. Why not in C++? Why not in Ada? OCAML? Forth? Lisp? There's technical reasons for (and against) all these, but the project (as in: a collection of people that actually do the work) is writing C code.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to wait a few weeks: after a few delays, [version 6.1 of the kernel should include Rust code](https://www.zdnet.com/article/linus-torvalds-rust-will-go-into-linux-6-1/). You can see it already [in `linux-next`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/rust) (where it’s been available since 5.19 was in preparation).

As for why the kernel in general doesn’t use Rust, there are a number of reasons, the first of which is inertia: currently the kernel contains over 22 million lines of actual C code (excluding comments), and changing a noticeable fraction of that to use another language is bound to take a long time. There are also a number of areas where Rust doesn’t quite work for the kernel, or needs a substantial amount of code to be rewritten in Rust before it’s actually useful — one of the main benefits of Rust is its escape analysis, and that doesn’t work well (if at all) for code which crosses language boundaries.

One approach that’s been pursued for a while is enabling the use of Rust for device drivers. See [Using Rust for kernel development](https://lwn.net/Articles/870555/) for an introduction, and [Rustaceans at the border](https://lwn.net/Articles/889924/) for recent coverage of the state of Rust in the kernel.

You might also find [Paul E. McKenney’s series “So You Want to Rust the Linux Kernel?”](https://paulmck.livejournal.com/62436.html) interesting.

Comment: Thank you for the information. :)